# Remove menu icon upon opening drawer

Tags: user-interface, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I'm trying to remove the menu icon upon opening the drawer and move the arrow icon to the left side of the drawer. I'm also trying to figure out why my arrow back function is not working to close it on mobile view. Any solution is appreciated.

I tried to make a conditions out of it but seems not to work. Here are the example of UI that I build on [play vuetifyjs](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqdWG1v2zYQ/iusuxUdUMnOe6NmQbJ1Awp0S1F02IemH2iJstlIokBRjtMg/33PkXqj7HhpjQIRecfjc+/Hfr6fXJZluKrFJJqcGZGXGTfi/Lpg7GwV8LK0n/idPQsCdvnhw9uPl//+8ZEFQUMAV8FXcsGNVEWQaH4rdHOErYJcJSL79XrS7E9aSqS5pH36w168YD8BgJHpXZjICgjuwjy5LJJ/ysGJUuic)

Comment: The link is wrong.

Comment: @Tolbxela Sorry I didnt notice that, I have updated the links to a valid link. Do take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround, let me know if others have a better approach!

```
<v-list-item>
   <v-icon v-if="$vuetify.display.mdAndUp && rail"> mdi-menu </v-icon>
   <v-icon
       v-if="$vuetify.display.mdAndUp && !rail"
       @click.stop="rail = true"
   >
    mdi-chevron-double-left
   </v-icon>
   <v-icon
       v-if="$vuetify.display.smAndDown && drawer"
       @click.stop="drawer = false"
   >
    mdi-chevron-double-left
   </v-icon>
</v-list-item>
```